# javascript and regularexpression?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

i have a doubt that whether javascript expression is better or regularexpression is better.
i mean for validation javascript is best or ?How it is different form each other? thank you.

Comment: surya what is 'javascript expression' ? and regular expression, regular expression used in what ? are you doing some ASP.net project?

Comment: yes i am doing asp.net project Mr. RageZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the kind of validation that you need.

Suppose if you need to compare two dates then regex won't be enough.

This one is a nice read

[12 Reasons to Learn and Use Regular Expressions](http://www.websiterepairguy.com/articles/re/12_re.html)

Answer (score 0):

Surya,

Javascript can help you to build some validation but **you should madder what implement the same input validation on the server side**.

So it's only to make it more user friendly, so you should start implementing your server input validation when you are done and if you have time add the javascript validation.